# Instagram-like cropping?

Tags: android, image-processing

Although it isn't obvious at first, in the Android Instagram app you can (after editing a photo) go back to the photo roll to view an old image. Then a frame appears with drag handles on the side; you can move the frame and resize it by dragging the handles, allowing you to crop to any part of the image.

How do I do this on Android? Is this a standard feature, is there a similar open source library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is [this](http://www.londatiga.net/featured-articles/how-to-select-and-crop-image-on-android/) along the lines of what you want?

Comment: Can 404 be the solution?

Comment: It's been a while, but doesn't show as a 404 for me. The article discusses a project at https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/AndroidImageCrop

Answer (score 5):

take look at this project. 
https://github.com/naver/android-imagecropview
This project is for imagecropview like instagram